# Binding click events in a for loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am creating a unordered list and a button in the for loop. I want to bind a click function for the buttons in the same for loop.

Tried with the concatenating option. It`s not working.

```
function displayFeeds(items){
    var ul = $('#listview');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
         var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].DeviceNames);
         li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].DeviceQuantity));
         li .append('<input type="button" value="Add" id="'+i+'">');
         // Enhance new button element
        li.append($('<hr>')); 
         ul.append(li); 


    $('#"+i+"').bind('click', function () {             
        console.log("called");
        var clickedID = this.id;
        console.log(clickedID);
        UpdateDeviceDetails(clickedID);             
    });
    }
}
```

What should I do here?

Comment: Have a look at this question [Javascript closure inside loops - simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Comment: You mean $( ' # ' + i + ' ').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing

```
$('#"+i+"').bind('click', function () {
```

to

```
$('#'+i).bind('click', function () {
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from the syntax error stopping your current code from working, appending `x` number of click handlers in a loop will be relatively slow. A better solution is to attach a delegate event to a single shared parent element. Try this:

```
function displayFeeds(items){
    var ul = $('#listview');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var li = $('<li/>').html(items[i].DeviceNames);
        li.append($('<li/>').html(items[i].DeviceQuantity));
        li.append('<input type="button" value="Add" class="add-input" />');
        li.append($('<hr>')); 
        ul.append(li); 
    }
}

// single event handler...
$('#listview').on('click', '.add-input', function() {
    UpdateDeviceDetails(this.id);             
});
```

You could even simplify that by just passing the reference of `UpdateDevideDetails` to the `click` handler, something like this:

```
$('#listview').on('click', '.add-input', UpdateDeviceDetails);

var UpdateDeviceDetails = function(el) {
    var id = el.id;
    // rest of your logic...
}
```

Also note that the HTML generated by your jQuery will be invalid - you cannot have an `li` as a direct child of another `li` element. All `li` elements should have a parent `ul` or `ol`.

Comment: Thanks much for ur response. I need ID to be passed to the parameter of the UpdateDeviceDetails(). The value of the ID should be like 0..1.. (i.e the value of i from the for loop).

Comment: @Ash all the methods in my answer will do that.